# Unable to create object/class in parse.com using .net SDK

Tags: c#, .net, parse-platform

I am trying to create a object/class via the .net SDK on parse. Here is my class below. I am calling the Initialize in the constructor and then calling the method. It runs successfully, but I am unable to see the data in the data browser on parse. I used NuGet to get the official client.

```
public class ParseManager
{
    public ParseManager()
    {
        ParseClient.Initialize("XXXX", "CXXXX");
    }

    public async void Example()
    {
        ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("Test");
        gameScore["score"] = 1337;
        gameScore["playerName"] = "Test User";
        await gameScore.SaveAsync();

    }
}
```

Edit: Here is how I am calling this class/method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var pm = new ParseManager();
   pm.Example();
}
```

Comment: What is `Example`? Where are you calling it in your code?

Comment: Here is my code that I call if from:                                     var pm = new ParseManager();
            pm.Example();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't seeing any data because your Console Application terminates after the last function call to `pm.Example()`

Two things you have to do:

1. Change `Example` to `async Task` instead of `async void`:

   ```
   public async Task Example()
   {
      ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("Test");
      gameScore["score"] = 1337;
      gameScore["playerName"] = "Test User";
      await gameScore.SaveAsync();
   }
   ```
2. Explicitly call `Task.Wait` on `Example`:

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      var pm = new ParseManager();
      pm.Example().Wait():
   }
   ```